# Magento 2.4.6 - Product Alerts no longer working

Tags: magento2.4.6

I've recently upgraded my system to Magento 2.4.6 and product alerts seem to have stopped working.

Upon investigation, I've found that they are added to the `magento_bulk` database table but don't seem to be inserted into the `queue_message` table.

Has anyone encountered this issue and is there a proposed solution?

Thank you